# Error: ng:areq - controllers in different files

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to separate every controller in my angular app, but I have this error:

```
23:51:38.389 "Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/ng/areq?p0=skillsController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
P/<@file:///C:/Users/Piotr/Desktop/ver%202/js/angular.min.js:6:421
sb@file:///C:/Users/Piotr/Desktop/ver%202/js/angular.min.js:22:41
Ta@file:///C:/Users/Piotr/Desktop/ver%202/js/angular.min.js:22:128
af/this.$get</<@file:///C:/Users/Piotr/Desktop/ver%202/js/angular.min.js:84:42
B@file:///C:/Users/Piotr/Desktop/ver%202/js/angular.min.js:62:118
v@file:///C:/Users/Piotr/Desktop/ver%202/js/angular.min.js:63:115
Vf/<@file:///C:/Users/Piotr/Desktop/ver%202/js/angular.min.js:72:397
e/<@file:///C:/Users/Piotr/Desktop/ver%202/js/angular.min.js:123:217
pf/this.$get</m.prototype.$eval@file:///C:/Users/Piotr/Desktop/ver%202/js/angular.min.js:137:442
pf/this.$get</m.prototype.$digest@file:///C:/Users/Piotr/Desktop/ver%202/js/angular.min.js:135:33
pf/this.$get</m.prototype.$apply@file:///C:/Users/Piotr/Desktop/ver%202/js/angular.min.js:138:234
g@file:///C:/Users/Piotr/Desktop/ver%202/js/angular.min.js:91:372
t@file:///C:/Users/Piotr/Desktop/ver%202/js/angular.min.js:95:492
ag/</v.onload@file:///C:/Users/Piotr/Desktop/ver%202/js/angular.min.js:97:31
"1 angular.min.js:111:399
e/<() angular.min.js:111
cf/this.$get</<() angular.min.js:84
e/<() angular.min.js:123
pf/this.$get</m.prototype.$eval() angular.min.js:137
pf/this.$get</m.prototype.$digest() angular.min.js:135
pf/this.$get</m.prototype.$apply() angular.min.js:138
g() angular.min.js:91
t() angular.min.js:95
ag/</v.onload() angular.min.js:97
```

pkApp.js:

```
angular.module('pkApp', ['Controllers']).value("version", "1.160110");
```

controllersModule.js:

```
angular.module('Controllers', []);
```

skillsController.js:

```
angular.module('Controllers', [])
    .controller('skillsController', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.skills = [
            "html",
            "css",
            "js",
            "jquery",
            "angularjs",
            "php",
            "mysql",
            "joomla"
        ];
    }]);
```

portfolioController.js:

```
angular.module('Controllers', [])
    .controller('portfolioController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.sites = [{
            name: "Site1",
            href: "http://www.site1.pl",
            img: "1"
        }, {
            name: "Site 2",
            href: "http://www.site2.pl",
            img: "2"
        }, {
            name: "Site 3",
            href: "http://www.site3.pl",
            img: "3"
        }];
    }]);
```

It looks like angular see new module and only first controller that was to it, next is treat as function?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple Solution could be:

1. Define a variable with your module in pkApp.js

   ```
   var app = angular.module('pkApp', []);
   ```
2. You can delete the controllersModule.js
3. Create your Controllers as follows:

   ```
   app.controller('skillsController', ['$scope', function($scope){
   $scope.skills = [
       "html",
       "css",
       "js",
       "jquery",
       "angularjs",
       "php",
       "mysql",
       "joomla"
   ];
   }]);
   ```

Same thing with your portfolio controller. It doesn't matter how many files you like to use for your controllers.

See also: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Hope, that helps...